# trying to find the maximum number of occurrences over time T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data recording the `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` (both `DATETIME2`) of a process for all of the year 2013.

My task is to find the maximum amount of times the process was being ran at any specific time throughout the year.

I have wrote some code to check every minute/second how many processes were running at the specific time, but this takes a very long time and would be impossible to let it run for the whole year.

Here is the code (in this case check every minute for the date 25/10/2013)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Hit
(
  ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Moment DATETIME2,
  COUNT INT
 )

DECLARE @moment DATETIME2 

SET @moment = '2013-10-24 00:00:00'

WHILE @moment < '2013-10-25'
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #Hit ( Moment, COUNT )

    SELECT @moment, COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.tblProcessTimeLog
    WHERE ProcessFK IN (25)
    AND @moment BETWEEN StartDateTime AND EndDateTime
    AND DelInd = 0

    PRINT @moment

    SET @moment = DATEADD(MINute,1,@moment)
END

SELECT * FROM #Hit
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

Can anyone think how i could get a similar result (I just need the maximum amount of processes being run at any given time), but for all year?

Thanks

Comment: I certainly wouldn't be using a loop, that's for sure. Do you want the max number of concurrent results per day for the whole year, or do you want just *one* result?

Comment: i just want one result, the maximum at any point throughout the year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '20130101'; -- the first day of the year you care about

;WITH m(m) AS 
(  -- all the minutes in a day
  SELECT TOP (1440) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) - 1
  FROM master..spt_values
),
d(d) AS 
(  -- all the days in *that* year (accounts for leap years vs. hard-coding 365)
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @d, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @d))) DATEADD(DAY, number, @d)
    FROM master..spt_values WHERE type = N'P' ORDER BY number
),
x AS
(  -- all the minutes in *that* year
  SELECT moment = DATEADD(MINUTE, m.m, d.d) FROM m CROSS JOIN d
)
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES -- in case more than one at the top
  x.moment, [COUNT] = COUNT(l.ProcessFK)
FROM x 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblProcessTimeLog AS l
  ON x.moment >= l.StartDateTime 
  AND x.moment <= l.EndDateTime
WHERE l.ProcessFK = 25 AND l.DelInd = 0
GROUP BY x.moment
ORDER BY [COUNT] DESC;
```

[See this post for why I don't think you should use `BETWEEN` for range queries, even in cases where it does semantically do what you want](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted, thank you! i have also taken note of your BETWEEN article.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table `T` whose rows represent some time segments.
This table could well be a temporary table (depending on your case).

Say:

`row 1 - [from=00:00:00, to=00:00:01)`
`row 2 - [from=00:00:01, to=00:00:02)`
`row 3 - [from=00:00:02, to=00:00:03)`

and so on.

Then just join from your main table
(`tblProcessTimeLog`, I think) to this table
based on the datetime values recorded in
`tblProcessTimeLog`.

A year has just about half million minutes
so it is not that many rows to store in `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently pulled some code from SO trying to solve the 'island and gaps' problem, and the algorithm for that should help you solve your problem.

The idea is that you want to find the point in time that has the most started processes, much like figuring out the deepest nesting of parenthesis in an expression:

( ( ( ) ( ( ( (deepest here, 6)))))

This sql will produce this result for you (I included a temp table with sample data):

```
    /*
    CREATE TABLE #tblProcessTimeLog
    (
        StartDateTime DATETIME2,
        EndDateTime DATETIME2
    )

    -- delete from #tblProcessTimeLog

    INSERT INTO #tblProcessTimeLog (StartDateTime, EndDateTime)
    Values ('1/1/2012', '1/6/2012'), 
        ('1/2/2012', '1/6/2012'),
        ('1/3/2012', '1/6/2012'), 
        ('1/4/2012', '1/6/2012'), 
        ('1/5/2012', '1/7/2012'),
        ('1/6/2012', '1/8/2012'),
        ('1/6/2012', '1/10/2012'), 
        ('1/6/2012', '1/11/2012'), 
        ('1/10/2012', '1/12/2012'), 
        ('1/15/2012', '1/16/2012') 
    ;
    */
    with cteProcessGroups (EventDate, GroupId) as
(
    select EVENT_DATE, (E.START_ORDINAL - E.OVERALL_ORDINAL) GROUP_ID
    FROM
    (
        select EVENT_DATE, EVENT_TYPE, 
        MAX(START_ORDINAL) OVER (ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, EVENT_TYPE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as START_ORDINAL,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, EVENT_TYPE) AS OVERALL_ORDINAL
        from
        (
            Select StartDateTime AS EVENT_DATE, 1 as EVENT_TYPE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDateTime) as START_ORDINAL
            from #tblProcessTimeLog

            UNION ALL

            select EndDateTime, 0 as EVENT_TYPE, NULL
            FROM #tblProcessTimeLog
        ) RAWDATA
    ) E
)
select Max(EventDate) as EventDate, count(GroupId) as OpenProcesses
from cteProcessGroups
group by (GroupId)
order by COUNT(GroupId) desc
```

Results:

```
EventDate   OpenProcesses
2012-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 5
2012-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 4
2012-01-15 00:00:00.0000000 2
2012-01-10 00:00:00.0000000 2
2012-01-08 00:00:00.0000000 1
2012-01-07 00:00:00.0000000 1
2012-01-11 00:00:00.0000000 1
2012-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 1
2012-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 1
2012-01-06 00:00:00.0000000 1
2012-01-16 00:00:00.0000000 1
```

Note that the 'in-between' rows don't give anything meaningful.  Basically this output is only tuned to tell you when the most activity was.  Looking at the other rows in the out put, there wasn't just 1 process running on 1/8 (there was actually 3).  But the way this code works is that by grouping the processes that are concurrent together in a group, you can count the number of simultaneous processes.  The date returned is when the max concurrent processes began. It doesn't tell you how long they were going on for, but you can solve that with an additional query. (once you know the date the most was ocurring, you can find out the specific process IDs by using a BETWEEN statement on the date.)

Hope this helps.